# Ubuntu 18.04 won't start due to a clock error related to windows being run on the same disc

Tags: startup

I've just installed ubuntu 18.04. It was running fine. And then the following screen appeared. I am new to Ubuntu and am not sure how to fix the problem described on the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of start-up screen]

Comment: Try to change your clock in bios. Add some number of hours needed to eliminate the difference between windows and Linux times for the first time.

Comment: @Gryu That doesn't answer the question. And even if it tried, using `timedatectl` is how you sync clocks between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you elaborate on using timedatect1, please?

Comment: Ok, thank you for this.

Comment: @Ca1 see `man timedatectl` (lower case L at the end) and note the `set-local-rtc` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the (initramfs) prompt, type:

`fsck -f /dev/sda5`

And that should fix your problem.

Have you been powering off your computer using the shutdown command, or by pressing and holding the power button? Use the shutdown command.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. I could not use the shutdown command when the screenshot I posted came up, so I had to use the power button. Is there a command-line shutdown command?

Comment: The fsck -f /dev/sda5  worked!!! Thanks again. This is a delightful experience for a newbie like me to get quick and effective help.

Comment: Ok, done, checkmark!